# Is a player limited to four In-Town Deed cards?

Tags: doomtown-reloaded

*Doomtown: Reloaded* comes with a very helpful player board that looks like this:

[image: Image of the Doomtown: Reloaded player board]

([Original image source](http://boardgamegeek.com/image/2055349/doomtown-reloaded))

Notably, there are four spots for In-Town Deed cards. Is this a hard limit? I didn't spot anything in the rules regarding the maximum number of deeds and since the board is optional, I'm not sure if it meant that this was a true limit or if it was just how many they decided to print on the board.

So is a player limited to four In-Town Deed cards? Or can they have as many as they want?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nope - they just only had room on the board for four. You can play as many deeds as you can pay for.

See page 19 of the rulebook, where they show a deed potentially being played 3 to the right of the Home, where there is no printed spot on the board.

Comment: See MasterAir's comments below. Also, on page 19 of the rulebook, the example diagram shows a new deed potentially being placed 3 to the right of the Home card (which there is no space for on the board).

Answer (score 1):

Steven Holder is correct. In Town Deeds can be played at either end of your street. DTR is a card game, the board has some useful information for new players, but the image of where to put your In Town Deeds is just a guide.

The rulebook states:
"Unless they say otherwise, all deeds are in town. Place an in-town deed at one end of your street or the other, adjacent to the in-town location on that end of your street."

(I don't have enough rep, or I would have just commented on his answer)